# Mozilla webapp manifest validation fails with "Error while requesting icon" and "Error while requesting launch_path"

Tags: manifest, firefox-os

I try to submit a webapp to Mozilla's Firefox Marketplace but the validation fails.

The manifest is located here: https://www.bonner-nacht.de/manifest.webapp

The validator complains:

> Error while requesting icon
>
> Error: A remote resource was requested, but an error prevented the request from completing. This may include connection, DNS, or HTTP issues.
>
> Requested resource: https://www.bonner-nacht.de/img/logos/BonnerNacht48.png
>
> webapp.manifest

and also

> Error while requesting launch_path

But you can perfectly access those resources from any client I tested. Also I am quiet sure that this did work a few days ago.

In Apache's log I can see that Mozilla's server downloads the manifest but does not continue to request the other resources.

Anyone knows what the problem could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reported a bug at https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=875142 and I figured out the cause of this problem. The webapp validator uses python-requests library for retrieving http resources which does not SSL support server name indication (SNI), which is needed if you operate multiple virtual hosts with different domain names on a single IP.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to replace the relative paths with the complete url of the icons

```
"icons": {
    "16": "https://www.bonner-nacht.de/img/logos/BonnerNacht16.png",
    "30": "https://www.bonner-nacht.de/img/logos/BonnerNacht30.png",
    "32": "https://www.bonner-nacht.de/img/logos/BonnerNacht32.png",
    "48": "https://www.bonner-nacht.de/img/logos/BonnerNacht48.png",
    "60": "https://www.bonner-nacht.de/img/logos/BonnerNacht60.png",
    "64": "https://www.bonner-nacht.de/img/logos/BonnerNacht64.png",
    "128": "https://www.bonner-nacht.de/img/logos/BonnerNacht128.png",
    "256": "https://www.bonner-nacht.de/img/logos/BonnerNacht256.png"
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your hint but this didn't work. Still the same errors.